# Find product without images and Product images without lable

Tags: magento-1.7, import, image

After lots of try finally I manage to import bulk of products in magento.

Now How I can do get SKU of product if:

1. products without images.

OR

1. Images without lable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images are stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`. You can get all the products that have images like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(entity_id) from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;
```

You can get the product ids without images like this:

```
SELECT entity_id from catalog_product_entity where entity_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(entity_id) from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery);
```

The labels of the images are stored in `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`. You can get the products with images without labels by checking the field `label` in that table.

Comment: Thanks man, really great help.

For label value_id refer to catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value_id and then you will get corresponding entity_id.

Comment: Tables were changed for later version so on Magento 2.3.7 the query looks like this: 
`SELECT entity_id from catalog_product_entity where entity_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(entity_id) from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity);`

Comment: For Magento 2.4.X:

SELECT entity_id from catalog_product_entity where entity_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(value_id) from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity);